The cake has burnt ON/AT/FROM the top
Someone is baking a cake, and when the cake comes out of the oven, she sees the surface has turned black while the rest looks good. So, when telling about should she say:
The cake has burnt on the top.
The cake has burnt at the top.
The cake has burnt from the top.
I checked NGRAM, they all seem to yield results. So, does that mean they are all used and correct?

The problem is that we'd more likely say: The top of the cake is burned. So, on, at and from are not needed. Bear in mind: burned from the top means that's where the burning started...The house burned from the top [down].

When we bake a cake the bottom is more likely to get burnt first. The top of the cake is burnt would mean the whole cake is burnt.

@JamesMathai - Depends where the heating element is in relation to the cake tin.

There are lots of results for e.g. "damaged at the top". "At the top" seems good to me. ("From" in this context implies motion.)

Practically "The cake has burnt", or "I've burnt the cake".  If you need to mention top then "The top of the cake has burnt".
If you must use a PP then "on the top" seems the most obvious in terms of literal meaning.


"Burnt on the top" suggests that the burning is only on the surface. You might be able to cut the top off and have a perfectly edible cake.

"Burnt from the top" suggests that the burning began at the top and worked its way down. I've never heard this said about a cake, but it would suggest that the burn went deeper.

"I've burnt the cake" would suggest the whole cake is ruined.


Although you said you found results for "at the top", for physical placement on a surface we tend to use "on". "At the top" tends to be used to describe conditions around, not on, the top of something. For example "there is snow on the mountain top" but "the air is thin at the mountain top". In your example, the burnt matter is physically touching the cake, so it is on it.
There are other expressions commonly used in cookery to suggest slight, superficial burning. "It's caught a little (on top)" is one way in British English to say that something has just begun to burn slightly.

If the top of the cake is actually badly burned, as you say, black:

The top of the cake is all burnt.

That would be a colloquial way of stating that it is badly burned.
"all" has an emphatic sense in additional to its literal sense: even if only half of the cake had burned, if the charring is bad, "all burnt" would still be OK.
